# Only one asp.net page through out

Tags: asp.net

I have created a web page but i want to restrict only one instance of the page should be running at all times. The scenarios are given as below.

1. First time - User launches the page by URL and page loads.
2. User types URL again in another window and it should say that a page is already open OR refresh the existing page.
3. User closes the window and tries again - new fresh page will be loaded.

Additional Details : I have a database, user authentication.

Tried So Far : Set a flag in DB-->> This method how do i redirect the user back to the page which is already opened.

Any ideas to implement this.?

Thanks in Advance for your opinions and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use a cookie which expires when the user closes the browser. However, all browser instances may need to be closed.

1. First time, there is no cookie and http_referer does not contain the same domain. (set cookie now)
2. http_referer contains the same domain
3. cookie expires and go back to (1)

Comment: How do i refresh the current page if the page is already open and user tries to open again in another window.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using cookies for this. Create a session-long cookie upon opening of the window and destroy it upon closing of the window. If a cookie already exists, you know the window is already open.

This of course relies on javascript and is easily got round. You can not use a server-side solution because it would be impossible to catch the closing of the browser window in order to clear the cookie.

Personally, I wouldn't try and restrict the opening of multiple windows but restrict the functionality available in each window. This approach would be much easier to control using a server-side approach, e.g. events fired in the window can be validated server-side.

Comment: How do i refresh the current page if the page is already open and user tries to open again in another window.

Comment: It depends entirely on how the new windows are being opened. If they are being opened using javascript, you can maintain a reference to the original window and reload it when a new one is opened. If the windows are being opened independently, then you would probably struggle to implement this.

Comment: URL will be triggered by a third party application. :(